# How to use Map to define a mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a product schema that I want to store in MongoDb as a map. The productId is a string value. I checked the Mongoose documentation but do not fully understand the example using map.  In currently have it as an array but I really want to store it as a map.  Here is my schema:

```json
        const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          productId: {type:String, required:true},
          name: String,
          category: String,
          code: Number,
       })

       const ProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        products: [ProductSchema],
       })

        // Map <productId, product> this is what I want to achieve
```

Comment: MongoDB stores data as a JSON data. There is not Map type in the JSON specification. The only option to have is to retrieve data from the database and instantiate a new `Map` from this data. Nevertheless the mapping from `productId` to `product` does not really make sense in this case, since `productId` is an attribute contained in the schema of `product`.

Comment: Mongoose does allow you to create maps for schemas.Also, the redundancy of the productId is  deliberate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   const ProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     products: {
       type: Map,
       of:ProductSchema        
   })
```